# Difference between ‘study on’ and ‘study into’

Tags: prepositions, difference

In the sentences

> This is the only study **on/into** the effect of X in aquatic birds.
>
> The studies **on/into** aquatic birds have been carried out on species A and B.

Which word do we use?

Learner’s Dictionary defines ‘on’ as:

> used to indicate the subject of something 
>   •   a book on [=about] North American birds
>   •   a discussion on current events

and ‘into’ as:

> relating to or concerning (something) 
>   •   an investigation into the causes of the accident

Am I right in thinking that ‘into’ is used in these contexts when the study is about the result of an action (based on Google searching for both usages)?

i.e. ‘study *on* birds’ and ‘study *into* the effect of X’. Or can they be used interchangeably?

Comment: You would not say "study into birds" because nothing is going into a bird. But you can get "into the effect(s) of ..."

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't reliably predict which preposition will be used in any particular context from its dictionary definition—see my Answer [here](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/131636/32). You have to learn, word by word, which particular preposition each verb, adjective or noun ‘selects’ or ‘licenses’ to express a particular meaning or relationship.

For instance, the verb *study* casts its field or topic as a direct object—*we studied the effect of X on aquatic birds*. When transitive verbs are nominalized, their direct objects are most often cast as preposition phrases headed by *of*:

> A study **of** the effect of X ...

Nominal *study* also licenses *on* PPs:

> A study **on** the effect of X ...

But *of* would be preferred if you went on to use an *on* PP as complement of a different word, with a different sense:

> A study of the effect of X **on** Y ...

*Study* does not license *into* PPs as complements, either as a noun or as a verb. You would find an *into* PP following *study* only as an adjunct or complement of another consituent:

> We studied *into* the night ... *here* into the night *is not a complement of* study *but an adjunct locating the action in time*.

The verb *investigate* likewise casts its field or topic as a direct object—*we investigated the effect of X on aquatic birds*—and its nominal derivative *investigation* likewise licenses *of* PPs:

> An investigation **of** the effect of X ...

*Investigation*, however, also licenses *into* PPs:

> An investigation **into** the effect of X ...

Here *investigation* is metaphorically treated like a process of digging into a formless mass to find the relevant information, as if with a probe or shovel.

The *into* construction tends to be used mostly in contexts where *investigation* designates the process of investigating—*we are conducting an investigation into the effect of X*. It is unusual to find *into* used when *investigation* designates the outcome—in the title of a paper, for instance, where the results are reported.

Often the nominal derivative will license the same prepositions as its mother verb. But this doesn't usually run backwards, from the noun to the verb. For instance, we never say:

> * We studied <s>**on**</s> the effect of X ...
>   * We investigated <s>**into**</s> the effect of X ...

These are not hard and fast “rules”, but they reflect ‘standard’ formal usage.

Comment: It took me a minute to figure out what you meant by "PPs" here. "Prepositional phrases", right?

Comment: Also, a quick search reveals that the noun "study" does sometimes license "into" phrases: https://www.google.com/search?q=%22a+study+into%22 . Nevertheless, I agree that it sounds slightly stilted to a native ear.

Comment: @GTonyJacobs Yup, PP=preposition phrase. Google Ngrams found *a study into* at about 2% of *a study of* in the middle of the 19th century, but this use dropped to near 0 by end of that century. It has indeed been rising again in the last 40 years or so--it's now at about 0.4%, or ; one instance of *a study into* for every 250 instances of *a study of*.

Comment: I think that in this type of question re studies on [some group of animals or people], it is safe to say that it is always study on.